# Restrict Commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I got this code it blocks access to `?hello` command for everyone except those user id in `LIST_OF_ID`  so i modified this by replacing `ctx.message.author.id` to `ctx.message.server.id`  now it bypasses for server also. so i added both code but now its not working for both user and server, only works for anyone. how to make it works for both server and user.

```
LIST_OF_SERVER_IDS = ['3557657657647676', '36567565756766767']
LIST_OF_USER_IDS = ['3557657657647676', '36567565756766767'] 

def is_any_user(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.author.id in ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

def is_any_server(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.server.id in ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_any_user(LIST_OF_USER_IDS)
@is_any_server(LIST_OF_SERVER_IDS)
async def hello(ctx):
     await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining two `is_any_user` decorators, you just keep the most recently defined, and lose the first one.  Give the server check a more representative name (after all, it's not checking `User`s, why have "user" in the name).  Then we can keep two whitelists of ids.  Since `commands.check` can chain, we simply decorate our command with both checks.

```
LIST_OF_SERVER_IDS = [3557657657647676, 36567565756766767, 343657687786435432]
LIST_OF_USER_IDS = [1, 2, 3]  
# Replace as needed.  Keep in mind that 0.16 ids are strings and 1.0 ids are integers


def is_any_user(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.author.id in ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

def is_any_server(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.server.id in ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_any_user(LIST_OF_USER_IDS)
@is_any_server(LIST_OF_SERVER_IDS)
async def hello(ctx):
     await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

Edit:

Use these version of the checks to try and debug what's going on

```
def is_any_user(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        if ctx.message.author.id in ids:
            print("Good author")
            return True
        else:
            print("Bad author")
            return False
    return commands.check(predicate)

def is_any_server(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        if ctx.message.server.id in ids:
            print("Good server")
            return True
        else:
            print("Bad server")
            return False
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

Edit2:

You can write a check that looks to see if a person is in the user whitelist *or* accessing the command from a server on the server whitelist.

```
def whitelists(users, servers):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.author.id in users or ctx.message.server.id in servers
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@whitelists(LIST_OF_USER_IDS, LIST_OF_SERVER_IDS)
async def hello(ctx):
     await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

Comment: @Demotry I assume those aren't the ids you're using in your program.  You should be seeing some output in the terminal you're running the bot on.  That should at least tell you which of the checks is failing.

Comment: @Demotry I added some dubugging statements in the above.  Try running these to see where the check is failing.  Double check the ids in your list (make sure they are strings if you are using the 0.16 version and ints if you're using the 1.0 version).  Are you seeing any error in the terminal?

Comment: when i tried `is_any_user` in list i got `Good author Good server` but when i tried for `is_any_server` i got error its big i will add above .

Comment: I don't understand.  You can only get the `Good Server` message if the server check ran successfully.  What error did you get?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but if your id is the only one in the list of user ids, then the command should fail when invoked by others.  Are you saying that other users are able to use the command despite not being in the list of user ids?

Comment: No when i add server ID in `LIST_OF_SERVER_IDS` members in that server also can't use commands.

Comment: Commands must satisfy all checks before they're run.  So the command would have to be invoked by someone who is both in the user id list and invoked from a server in the server id list.

Comment: See my second edit.  The combined check there should work for your needs

Comment: Was missing a colon `:`, try now

Comment: Oops, `author`, not `user`

Comment: hello now i splitting bot.py files using cogs. so now i need to use `def whitelists(users, servers):` in main py or all py files.

Comment: Define it once, then `import` it into all the places you want to use it.  You should probably create a `utils.py` file or similar to prevent circular imports.

Comment: `from main import whitelists` does it works. Then what is utils.py what to add in that file.

Comment: If you have some other file `a.py` that you want to use `whitelist` in, and `main.py` imports `a.py`, then you want to avoid a scenario in which `a.py` imports `main.py` and `main.py` imports `a.py`.  You would do this by creating a third file that imports from neither.

Comment: So can I move all functions to functions.py and do `from function import whitelists, is_any_server` in all files.

Comment: So how to make this whitelists function reverse as blacklists for server and user ID. Which blocks user and server in `list of ids` with custom message.

Comment: Switch `in` to `not in` and `or` to `and` in `predicate`

Comment: See the [documentation for checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) it includes examples of using exceptions to fail checks

Comment: Hello @PatrickHaugh yours `edit2` is working fine but sometimes it leaves error in bash, but still it runs fine bot not crashes so what is this error cause.  `in predicate
    return ctx.message.author.id in users or ctx.message.server.id in servers
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: If the message is a private message, then the `server` will be `None`.